# Are Python coroutines actually used in a project?

Tags: python, coroutine

I read [this page](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/) on coroutines from David Beazley a while ago, and I wondered if any actual Python-based software made use of them ?

How is it coroutines seem like the most unused feature in Python ?

Comment: A year later, and I'm wondering the same thing.  It appears that the answer is largely, "no".  I'm hoping this comment will float this question back onto the front page where maybe we'll find a more current answer.

Comment: Incidentally, for people who find there way here, take the time to read that article from David Beazley -- it's fascinating.

Answer (score 4):

The [LEPL](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/) parsing library [uses coroutines](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/features.html?highlight=coroutines) to implement [trampolines](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/implementation.html#trampolining), which allow "infinite recursion".

Answer (score 3):

Twisted's [defer.inlineCallbacks](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.html#inlineCallbacks) turns your functions into coroutines.

Answer (score 2):

Since Python is really rich with (asynchronous) frameworks,I show two framework here which is based coroutine:

1.[Eventlet](http://eventlet.net/) is a concurrent networking library for Python，Coroutines ensure that the developer uses a blocking style of programming that is similar to threading, but provide the benefits of non-blocking I/O.

2.[Chiral](http://git.emarhavil.com/chiral.git) is a lightweight coroutine-based networking framework for high-performance internet and Web services.

Answer (score 1):

Also Tornado advises to use them [in their documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of projects in python3 that use coroutines. Check on www.asyncio.org for resources.

For an arbitrary listing:

- [Curio](http://curio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a concurrency framework by David Beazley (doesn't use asyncio)
- aiozmq implements async ZMQ transport, using coroutines
- aioredis allows async Redis operations using coroutines